# Access an element inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the div structure is

```
<div><svg id="apple"></svg></div>
```

I use the below to access the svg file.

```
document.getElementById('apple').parentNode.innerHTML
```

My question is, how do I access the svg when the div structure is as below.

```
<div id="apple"><svg></svg></div>
```

Comment: You're also able to use native document.querySelector('#apple svg') or document.getElementById('apple ').children with specified position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jquery you would do this:

```
$("#apple svg")
```

In Javascript you would do this

```
document.getElementById('apple').innerHTML
```

Comment: you could also do it with apple.getElementsByTagName('svg') that returns an array

Comment: You are correct Juan, but it would just be a little longer. But it works both ways

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty standard practice in JavaScript.

To select all `<svg>` elements use:

```
var svgs=document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
```

To select the first `<svg>` element within `<div id="apple">`

```
var x=document.getElementById('apple').getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
```

> Note: getElementsByTagName() returns an array of elements and [0]
>   selects first out of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#apple").children("svg")
```

This will get you the `svg` children of your `apple` div.

If you just want the first match, you'd do this:

```
$("#apple").children("svg").first()
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing how this can be used: https://jsfiddle.net/o7xyrbbL/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var mySvg = $('#apple').children('svg');
```

Comment: The question never mentioned jQuery, so you should explain that requirement in your answer.  Also, SO answers should provide more explanation than just a line of code.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I'm still new to the participation here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this way.

```
  <div id="apple"><svg></svg></div>

    <script>

        var svg = document.getElementById('apple').firstChild // with this you reference the svg tag.

    </script>
```